# How to create Payload Dynamically in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am invoking a wso2 DSS service which returns me data like:

```
<IdentifierCollection xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <Identifier>
        <One>1</One>
    <Two>2</Two>
    <Three>3</Three>
    </Identifier>
</IdentifierCollection>
```

To invoke Dss my esb code is:

```
<payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <p:GetIdentifier xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/">
                  <xs:ID xmlns:xs="http://tempuri.org/">$1</xs:ID>
               </p:GetIdentifier >
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg expression="get-property('ID')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send receive="ResponseOfGetIdentifier">
            <endpoint key="IdentifierEP"/>
         </send>
```

Now in my ResponseOfGetIdentifier Sequence i am capturing all data in properties

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ResponseOfGetIdentifier">
   <iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/" preservePayload="true" attachPath="//p:EntriesCollection" expression="//p:EntriesCollection/p:Entries" id="IterateForResponse">
      <target>
<sequence>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org" name="ResponseOne" expression="//p:Identifier/p:one" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org" name="ResponseTwo" expression="//p:Identifier/p:Two" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org" name="ResponseThree" expression="//p:Identifier/p:Three" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<payloadFactory>
         <format>
<tns:ProductIdentifier xmlns:tns="http://globalArther.products.com">
<IdentifierProducts>
<Product1>$1</Product1>
<Product2>$2</Product>
<Product3>$3</Product3>
</IdentifierProducts>
</tns:ProductIdentifier>
</format>
<args>
<arg expression="get-property('ResponseOne')"/>
<arg expression="get-property(''ResponseTwo)"/>
<arg expression="get-property('ResponseThree')"/>
</args>
</payloadFactory>
</sequence>
</target>
   </iterate>
</sequence>
```

Since my dss response contains only one iteration of Identifier node hence above code is working but when my identifier node count is more than one i.e

```
<IdentifierCollection xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <Identifier>
        <One>1</One>
    <Two>2</Two>
    <Three>3</Three>
    </Identifier>
<Identifier>
        <One>a</One>
    <Two>b</Two>
    <Three>c</Three>
    </Identifier>
</IdentifierCollection>
```

, since my payload can take only one data it takes the second iteration data and shows me only single result as:

```
<tns:ProductIdentifier xmlns:tns="http://globalArther.products.com">
    <IdentifierProducts>
    <Product1>a</Product1>
    <Product2>b</Product>
    <Product3>c</Product3>
    </IdentifierProducts>
    </tns:ProductIdentifier>
```

But i want my response as :

```
<tns:ProductIdentifier xmlns:tns="http://globalArther.products.com">
        <IdentifierProducts>
        <Product1>1</Product1>
        <Product2>2</Product>
        <Product3>3</Product3>
        </IdentifierProducts>
<IdentifierProducts>
        <Product1>a</Product1>
        <Product2>b</Product>
        <Product3>c</Product3>
        </IdentifierProducts>
</tns:ProductIdentifier>
```

So now my question is how can i do that i.e how can i make my payload dynamic i.e. i want to add every iteration in my payload.
Looking forward to your answers.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payload is kind of static. You need to use XSLT mediator to achieve this .That is, you have to write XSLT script to make the iteration logic.